# Camel jms: How to set replyTo

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, message-queue

this is the route:

```
 <from uri="timer://tick-tock-timer?period=50000" />
          <transform>
          <simple>Message at ${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</simple>
        </transform>
          <to uri="activemq:queue:inbox" pattern="InOut" />
         </route>



<route id="consumer14">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:inbox"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
       <transform>
          <simple>${in.body}&#13;</simple>
       </transform>
        <log message="${body}"/>
      </route>
```

i try to send reply indicates that the message was received and i dont know where it should be.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about the replyTo option at the Camel JMS component doc page:

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

You can tell what the replyTo should be

```
<to uri="activemq:queue:inbox?replyTo=foo" pattern="InOut" />
```

Then the 2nd route will automatic use that when sending back the reply message when its at the end of the route.

Also pay attention to the various kind of reply queues, such as temporary, shared or exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! with `<to uri="activemq:queue:inbox?replyTo=foo&amp;replyToType=Exclusive" pattern="InOut" />` i got this message error: `The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-SMART-51182-1447233432669-0-6 not received on destination: queue://foo. Exchange[Message: Message at 2015-11-11 10:18:04`